# Exact value of $\tan^{-1}(\sqrt3/3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm trying to figure out how to find the exact value of $\tan^{-1}(\sqrt3/3)$. I tried doing the following because I couldn't see any points where $\sqrt3/3$ lies on the Unit Circle $$\tan^{-1}(\sqrt3/3)=x$$ $$\tan(x)=\sqrt3/3$$ but from here I'm lost, I thought about maybe multiplying top and bottom by $1/\sqrt3$ but I just ended up with the same thing. Any suggestions.

Comment: To type $\tan^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})$, type \tan^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}) in math mode.  To type $$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)$$ type \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right) in display math mode.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, the best solution is to rationalize the numerator
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{3}{3\sqrt{3}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

But lets say that completely went by us. One solution may be to try to build  right triangle with an angle $\theta$ such that $$\tan\theta = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$$

Setting $opposite = \sqrt{3}$, and $adjacent=3$, by Pythagoras we have
$$hypotenuse = \sqrt{opposite ^2 + adjacent^2}=\sqrt{12}=2\sqrt{3}$$

Notice that the hypotenuse is exactly twice that of the of the opposite side.
[image]

By reflecting this triangle onto itself, we can build an equilateral triangle, giving us an angle of $\theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$

Comment: Interesting (+1)

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}=\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\pi}6$$

Comment: but how did you go from $$\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}=\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$? @GoodDeeds

Comment: Since $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: @Billy  Observe that $3 = \sqrt{3} \cdot \sqrt{3}$.  Hence, $$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3} \cdot \sqrt{3}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: I feel like an idiot, but I definitely see that 100%. How about the $\frac{\pi}{6}$ part @N.F.Taussig

Comment: @Billy What are your starting assumptions? Based on what should the answer be?

Answer (score 1):

By Pythagoras, the height of an equilateral triangle of unit side length is $\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$. Conclude from this that $\tan 30^\circ = \frac{1/2}{\sqrt 3 2}=\frac{\sqrt 3}3$.

Answer (score 1):

The range of the arctangent (inverse tangent) function is $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.  Since 
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} > 0$$
we may conclude that 
$$\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right) \in \left(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
so we are looking for an answer in the first quadrant.

Since 
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3} \cdot \sqrt{3}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}$$
we are looking for a first quadrant angle $\theta$ with 
\begin{align*}
\sin\theta & = \frac{1}{2}\\
\cos\theta & = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
\end{align*}
The only such angle is 
$$\theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$$
Hence,
$$\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right) = \frac{\pi}{6}$$

Answer (score 0):

> Notice, when $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\Re[z]>0$:
>
> - $$\arg[z]=\arctan\left(\frac{\Im[z]}{\Re[z]}\right)$$

In your example we can say:

- $$\Re[z]=3$$
- $$\Im[z]=\sqrt{3}$$

So:

$$z=\Re[z]+\Im[z]i=3+\sqrt{3}i$$

And we now that:

$$\arg[3+\sqrt{3}i]=\frac{\pi}{6}$$

So:

$$\arg[3+\sqrt{3}i]=\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)=\frac{\pi}{6}$$